Некорректная работа мини-корзины Woocommerce
Прошу помощи знающих людей в следующей ситуации. В интернет-магазине (связка wordpress + woocommerce) начала глючить функция отображения мини-корзины, причина не ясна. Симптомы следующие:
Если добавить товар в корзину на главной или странице категорий через карточку товара  и сразу навести курсор на иконку корзины - мини-корзина отображается, всё как надо.

Обновляем эту же страницу по F5, либо переходим на другой URL и снова наводим курсор на иконку корзины - мини-корзина уже не работает. Пытается грузить (крутится иконка загрузки), но безрезультатно.

И еще интересно, что если добавить товар в корзину на самой странице товара (не главной или категории), то содержимое мини-корзины не работает ни при каких условиях...
Подскажите, куда копать?
P.S. Сама страница корзины товаров по прямой ссылке открывается без проблем.

Для начала см в логи ошибок на сервере и консоле браузера.

Я особо ошибок там не вижу. Вы могли бы помочь, если я скину адрес сайта?

Да, не помешает указать адрес сайта прямо в вопросе.
